# How do i navigate to a link using IJavaScriptExecutor in selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

In selenium C# we generally use driver.Navigate to navigate to the link

Example:

```
driver.Navigate(driver.FindElement(linkLocator).GetAttribute("href"));
```

But i want to know is there any way to achieve this using IJavaScriptExecutor?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just click the link? Why pull the href and navigate?

Comment: You can't completely change your question. You've accepted an answer so the new question will make no sense. You need to start a new question and revert this one back.

Comment: @JeffC, I used that(driver.FindElement(linkLocator).GetAttribute("href")) to get the url from the DOM and use the url to navigate to the link.

Comment: You need to stop editing the question. It's been answered. Leave it as is. If you want to ask another question, start a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the link using selenium and you can either use `ExecuteJavaScript` from Selenium or `ExecuteScript` from `IJavaScriptExecutor`.

Using selenium built in method **ExecuteJavaScript**

```
driver.ExecuteJavaScript<string>("window.location.href = '" + driver.FindElement(linkLocator).GetAttribute("href"); + "';");
```

Using **IJavaScriptExecutor**

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
executor.ExecuteScript("window.location.href = " + driver.FindElement(linkLocator).GetAttribute("href"); + ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it-

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `IJavaScriptExecutor`, selenium has built in method `ExecuteJavaScript`

```
string href = driver.FindElement(linkLocator).GetAttribute("href");
driver.ExecuteJavaScript<string>("window.location.href = '" + href + "';");
```